# View not refreshing following post in Razor MVC using datatable

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

As per subject.  The view looks like this.

```
@using System.Globalization
@model IEnumerable<TaskEngine.WebUI.Models.TaskViewModel>

<script src="../../Scripts/progress-task.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',
            data: { from: "10/01/2014", to: "10/14/2014" },
            dataType: "html",
            success: function () {
                alert('Success');
            },
            error: function (request) {
                alert(request.responseText);
            }
        });
    });

</script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
              <div class="span16">
                  <div id="sitename">
                      <a href="/" id="logo">xxxxxxxx</a>
                      <span class="name">Workbasket</span>
                  </div>

                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="span16">
                          <table class="table table-striped table-condensed" id="task-table">
                              <thead>
                                  <tr>
                                      <th class="left">Client</th>
                                      <th class="left">Task</th>
                                      <th class="left">State</th>
                                      <th class="left">Assigned By</th>
                                      <th class="left">Assigned To</th>
                                      <th class="left">Date Opened</th>
                                      <th class="left">Date Due</th>
                                     @* <th class="left">Date Closed</th>*@
                                      <th class="left">Outcomes</th>
                                </tr>
                              </thead>
                              <tbody>
                                  @foreach (var task in Model)
                                  {
                                      <tr>
                                          <td><span>@task.ClientId</span></td>
                                          <td><span class="nowrap">@task.TaskDescription</span></td>
                                          <td><span class="nowrap">@task.CurrentState</span></td>
                                          <td><span >@task.AssignedBy.Replace("CORPORATE\\", "").Replace(@".", " ")</span></td>
                                          <td><span>@task.AssignedTo.Replace("CORPORATE\\", "").Replace(@".", " ")</span></td>
                                           <td><span>@task.DateOpened.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")</span></td>
                                          <td><span>@task.DateDue.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")</span></td>
                                     @*     <td><span>@(task.DateClosed.HasValue ? task.DateClosed.Value.ToShortDateString() : " - ")</span></td>*@
                                          <td>
                                              <span class="nowrap">
                                                  @Html.DropDownList(
                                                      "Outcomes", 
                                                      new SelectList(task.Outcomes, "Id", "Name"), "---Please Select ---",
                                                      new Dictionary<string, object>
                                                      {
                                                          {"data-case-id", @task.CaseId }, {"data-task-log-id", @task.TaskLogId}, {"data-client-id", @task.ClientId}
                                                      })
                                              </span>
                                          </td>
                                      </tr>
                                  }
                              </tbody>
                          </table>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>

    <div class="modal hide span8" id="complete-task-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="complete-task-header" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="complete-task-header">Complete Task</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span8">
                    <div class="alert alert-info">
                        <label id="CurrentState"></label>
                        <label id="NewState"></label>
                        <label>Generated Tasks</label>
                        <ul id="task-list">
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <form id="form">
                <input type="hidden" id="task-log-id" name="taskLogId" />
                <input type="hidden" id="case-id" name="caseId" />
                <input type="hidden" id="outcome-id" name="triggerId" />
                <input type="hidden" id="client-id" name="clientId" />
                <div id="popup">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button  class="btn" id="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Go Back</button>
            <button  class="btn btn-primary" id="confirm-task">Confirm</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the controller method.

```
    public ActionResult Index(DateTime? from, DateTime? to)
    {
        var usergroups = GetGroups(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);

        var model = _taskLogger.GetTasks(from, to)
            .Select(task => new TaskViewModel
            {
                TaskLogId = task.TaskLogId,
                CaseId = task.CaseId,
                ClientId = task.ClientId,
                TaskDescription = task.Description,
                AssignedBy = task.AssignedBy,
                AssignedTo = task.AssignedTo.Trim(),
                DateOpened = task.DateCreated,
                DateClosed = task.DateClosed,
                DateDue = task.DateDue
            }).ToList()
            .Where(x => IsAvailableToUser(x.AssignedTo, usergroups))
            .OrderBy(x => x.DateDue);

        foreach (var task in model)
        {
            var workflow = _workflowEngine.GetCase(task.CaseId);

            task.CurrentState = workflow.State.ToNonPascalString();
            task.Outcomes = workflow.GetPermittedTriggers().OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
        }

        ModelState.Clear();
        return View(model);
    }
```

When the model is returned following the ajax post, the dataset is different, as expected, however, within the datatable in the view it still displays the old data.

Having done some googling on this issue, I've tried clearing the modelstate but that makes no difference and from what I've read, it only seems to affect HTMLHelpers anyway.

I'm not sure if this is an issue with the datatable or just a refresh issue with the view itself.  Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: The Ajax call doesnt magically update the view when the model changes, you have to append the result to the page. The view is returned as data in the success callback.

Comment: The result is being appended to the page in the foreach, yet the page does not reflect the additional results.

Comment: just thinking out loud - have you tried to specify a type? i.e. Post

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't seem to make any difference.  I can sit and step through the code, watching it put the additional data into the view and yet the view doesn't change.  This is why I'm thinking it's a refresh issue, but my knowledge of MVC is minimal so I have no idea what's going on "under the hood" as it were.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax calls stays on the same page. If you want to update the page with the view returned by `public ActionResult Index(DateTime? from, DateTime? to)` then you need to add it to the DOM in the success callback

```
$.ajax({
  url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',
  data: { from: "10/01/2014", to: "10/14/2014" },
  dataType: "html",
  success: function (data) {
    $('#someElement').html(data); // add the returned html to the DOM
  },
  ....
});
```

but looking at the code in the controller it appears to be the same view as the original view so perhaps you really want to redirect rather than stay on the same page

Comment: I put the table in a partial view and did as you suggested.  It works fine.  Thanks.